# How to read Post reply to a site

Tags: java

I am working to get the response from the site by sending the post parameters programmatically using httpclient api but unable to get the desired response.

This is what i have tried:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    try
    {
        String bin = "--FONT PATH--";
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.freefontconverter.com/index.php");

        MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        File fileToUpload = new File(bin);
        FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(fileToUpload,"application/octet-stream");
        entity.addPart("fontFile", fileBody);
        entity.addPart("outputFormat", new StringBody("ttf"));
        entity.addPart("submit", new StringBody("Convert"));

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

        if (resEntity != null)
        {
                 //Want a ttf response as attachment file here------------------
        }
        EntityUtils.consume(resEntity);
    }
    finally
    {
        httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }
```

is there any thing which i forget to code or any alternative to this?

Comment: What do you mean with "Unable to get the desired response"? What is the exact error (if any)?

Comment: what do yo get in return? you should try to use fiddler to check the http response. and why not use a catch (Exception e) to debug ?

Comment: i got a text/html response(200) here but actually the form gives a ttf file.